# Missing stack traces for crashes in Firebase Crashlytics console

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I have an iOS app connected to Firebase Crashlytics. For some crashes the console does not show stack traces (or any other data for that matter), only an error message saying "There was an error loading your session":

[image: Crashlytics screenshot]

This does not happen for all crash events: for some of them, crash data is properly shown. I have tried to get in touch with Firebase support, but no luck so far.

Is anyone experiencing this issue? Any hints about what might be causing it?

Alternatively is there a way to download the raw crash data from Crashlytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase tech support has confirmed that the problem is that their backend is having trouble storing the crash data:

> what appears to be happening is that the stacktraces for these crashes are too large for Crashlytics to persist to storage. Normally, Crashlytics removes extra threads and manages to store the crash, but if the frames within the threads are too large, we would encounter issues storing the crashes.

Also they say that since the problem is that they did not manage to store the crashes, they cannot provide any way to download the raw crash data either.

They further mention that they are considering implementing ways to increase our size capacity, but they don't have a specific timeline for that, and they consider this a "feature request".

Needless to say I strongly disagree on this last bit, given that:

1. On iOS it is not really possible to install more than one exception handler / crash reporter
2. So basically you need to choose WHO you will be sending your crash reports to
3. If the crash reporting engine then fails to persist your data, then the data is essentially lost

It's difficult to understand how "not losing your data" is considered a feature request rather than a severe bug.

Comment: Surprised to see a tool which is supposed to help us catch bugs is so buggy! Same issue persists in 2022

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this.

If you manually search for the issue title in the issues list and open it from the search tool, the stack trace appears.